# Type Alias as Discriminating Union

Tags: typescript

I've written a fairly complex definition file to match the behavior of an existing JavaScript library

```
export declare interface XcodeBaseFileTreeObject {
    path: string;
    includeInIndex?: 0 | 1;
    usesTabs?: 0 | 1;
    indentWidth?: number;
    tabWidth?: number;
    wrapsLines?: 0 | 1;
}

export declare interface XcodeUngroupedFileTreeObject extends XcodeBaseFileTreeObject {
    sourceTree: `"<absolute>"` | "SOURCE_ROOT" | "DEVELOPER_DIR" | "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" | "SDKROOT";
    name: string;
}

export declare interface XcodeGroupedFileTreeObject extends XcodeBaseFileTreeObject {
    sourceTree: `"<group>"`;
}

export declare type XcodeAbstractFileTreeObject = XcodeGroupedFileTreeObject | XcodeUngroupedFileTreeObject;

export declare type PBXBaseFileReference = XcodeAbstractFileTreeObject & {
    readonly isa: "PBXFileReference";
    fileEncoding?: 4 | 10;
    lineEnding?: 0 | 1 | 2;
    languageSpecificationIdentifier?: string;
    xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier?: string;
    plistStructureDefinitionIdentifier?: string;
};

export declare type XcodeFileType = "archive.ar" | "archive.asdictionary" | "archive.binhex";

export declare type PBXInferredFileReference = PBXBaseFileReference & {
    lastKnownFileType: XcodeFileType;
};

export declare type PBXExplicitFileReference = PBXBaseFileReference & {
    explicitFileType: XcodeFileType;
};

export declare type PBXFileReference = PBXInferredFileReference | PBXExplicitFileReference;
```

Some union types as properties have been shortened for brevity, but the gist here is that I have a discriminating union from which another type is meant to inherit from, and in turn, another discriminating union is meant to inherit from *that* type. When I use the union at the bottom of the tree in a function like this:

```
function getFileType(file: PBXFileReference): XcodeFileType {
    return file.lastKnownFileType ?? file.explicitFileType;
}
```

I get an error that neither `lastKnownFileType` nor `explicitFileType` exist on `PBXFileReference`. In fact, neither property even comes up in the autocomplete when I'm writing that. I was expecting that to act as a typical discriminating union, where if one of those values isn't defined, it falls back on the other one definitely existing. How can I achieve the structure I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary expression and use `in` to check for the property before accessing it:

```
function getFileType(file: PBXFileReference): XcodeFileType {
  return 'lastKnownFileType' in file ? file.lastKnownFileType : file.explicitFileType;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDgSwHYzBQBm6y2AGshEgELoDOwAYjqsACpbADyARgCsU8AN4AoOJLhh0MABYAuOAxhR8AcwDcEqfjQBXJAEk8JpCAD8SgAxwAPnACM2qXH1MGHdHwZW4th2cdSXwkAgB1HAR5Pzx9AFs%20IhcpGG9I6LlYhKSoFMkAdyh0MAYAGXxgXxt7J20AXzExUEhYRBQMLFwCIlJyOCoaYABVPHUoCH0wYARWdi5gXkFhOFBCPAQGAeo6RhY2Tm5%20IWRRYOVJqHIF4CUAAwAiAB5vBghUfUIAPge72oeAMo8YYAJQAwgBRAD6IJ4PA4D3%20ABEIQA1CFlHgABQhIKhSKMIMRDgetGGRjKHChWNhSOGYI4APxhOJcEBSIA0rD4Q98nA8Oh4rdlKoNA0mi1oPAkGhMNh8IQSGRKDtgABxCZTGZzQ6LY4rNbADZbQa7Jg6m7605wcSuN76K664WPJ7jSZgH53cXNcBS9qyrowACe022QwAgj5VGQYBajstrQBeMNIDXu7UHS0J%20AOU0jMaa6azTPxk4wbQ%201rSjpyuDB0NY2gUejmg4g4DEIhG-rJvORlTFU5xvXZuAAMht5yw6AQEDwqCDuAY6CUD0bFB17c7WDw5F552IBwhu5oGj8ABZao5rHzUJVjwgzzVArUAEy39BjfTodTAAHTZAcEPZBZBwOcjDCGAgJwIg-AHMVzhAZAyk-dRv1-f8UGgkCoPAyDoNgpR4LGPkwDvFQAVUfRTgdYAkQ7fAcFw0x8MPQiRTUEixHqCtJTaGVOmwesVSGC0Q2wZMHkwZA5BwAA3YAADpMFZKSrlkhTlIYR9TjAgUoCDVTpI0pS%20HwORQH3Ss-QE2thLgdcTG3LBi3YLcu13CSHKbFt9jcjsPP6CdbSkDAVA5PAIAKPAxOmJQ81i4AGl431%20JrQNxO8igIXAO9ANjNsAp3Hsst8zciu7bBgvOFo8qYxL4tVRLkolVLqwDITMvXcrt0quBk0cvBnIzfzes82p1xysicHynrAqSpoxGIfRd2YuBfwK%20ZxIACkPdglG6wqxvIABKRrRMzTKQqwGAHTwOAAHIwpgCKopiy7pge7o4D27ALB%20g5FOe17osSuAlF%20xTapm%20qPoW%20ogA)